# Odd Excel Formula - Group by one cell by max of another cell and total a third cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have a column of account numbers that vary in count from 2 to 5, each count represents a different state in column 2, column 3 is the variable I need to sum. Criteria is to take the max count of all states and make all states for that account equal to the max state, with the sum of all applicable states (with no duplication). Hope that makes sense. I can't figure it out. Ending result would be one row per account with the highest value state and the sum of all states.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69487438/edit) to provide us the expected outcome? It's not clear to me what it is you want, but maybe `SUMIF` or `MAXIF`?

Comment: Can you add a few manually calculated expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pivot on your data and in Value Field settings use Max instead of the default Sum. Iffff I understood your question, this may help.

Comment: That doesn't work. I need to add up all of the state totals and have the label be the state that had the highest value.